# Figure out when to click a jbutton

Tags: java, swing

```
//spot is a boolean variable set to false and only switched to true when current object came from left,right,up,or down.
private boolean compare(Object c, Object pre)
{
    //  boolean result=false;
    for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++)
        {
            if (c.equals(board[x][y]))
                if (pre.equals(board[x - 1][y]))
                {
                    spot = true;
                }
        }
    }
    return spot;
}
```

Purpose of this is I have a two `jbutton` array and can only click when it came from a previous spot which was left, right, up or down. Cannot click diagonal spots or far away Spots from last clicked.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    if (c == 0)
    {
        first = FindButton(e.getSource());
        btn.setText(player);
        togglePlayer();
        c++;
        return;
    }
    if ((((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("") || ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals(player)) && hasWinner == false)
    {
        if (c < 6)
            if (e.getSource().equals(first))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player " + player + " is winner");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        //if(e.g//next to prev)
        btn.setText(player);
        hasWinner();
        togglePlayer();
        c++;

        last = FindButton(e.getSource());
        //pre=e.getSource()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a member variable in the class to hold the previous button.

Update it after you've processed the button click by assigning the last to pre.

If you start with no buttons initialized i.e pre is null then you could directly assign first to pre. Hope someone else comes in with a better answer.